# Update nested documents with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to perform updates on my mongoDB document which has the following structure :

```
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  questions: [{
    name: String,
    correct_answer: String,
    answers: [{
      name: String,
    }],
  }],
}
```

Is there any way of using mongoose's `findByIdAndUpdate()` to update only provided fields ? Both top level values and nested documents' ?

The idea here is would be to provide an object like

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "Updated quiz name",
        "questions": [
            {
                "_id": "123abc", // Targetted question's id
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "_id": "456def", // Targetted answer's id
                        "name": "Updated answer name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and perform updates only of specified nested documents using their ids.

I hope everything is clear cause its still a bit confused in my mind.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: example dataset

Let's say I have this document :

```
{
    "name": "Quiz name",
    "questions": [
        {
            "name": "Question #1",
            "correct_answer": "Answer #1",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "name": "Answer #1",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f9"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer #2",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0fa"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer #3",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0fb"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer #4",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0fc"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f8"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f7",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to use some mongoose update method (if it does exist) that could use an object like

```
{
    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f7",
    "questions": [
        {
            "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f8",
            "name": "Updated Question #1",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "name": "Updated Answer #3",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0fb"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I expect the result to be

```
{
    "name": "Quiz name",
    "questions": [
        {
            "name": "Updated Question #1", // Updated
            "correct_answer": "Answer #1",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "name": "Answer #1",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f9"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer #2",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0fa"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Updated Answer #3", // Updated
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0fb"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Answer #4",
                    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0fc"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f8"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "61c0ab84d7e616076385c0f7",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can give us a sample dataset and the corresponding output after you apply the update with the object.

Comment: I edited my post, I hope this will be clearer

Comment: It is much better now :) Can we know that is there any assumption on the input object? (e.g. is there any limitation on the size of `questions` and `answers` arrays?)